# RTF Editor - Edit Existing Tables?

Tags: 2013, 2013-sp1, rtf

Is there any way to use the table editor in an RTF field to edit an existing table without losing any of the values?  It looks like the answer is no.  Do you know of any online tools that can do this?  I looked a bit and wasn't able to find any.

This isn't too much of an issue for me, but not all the content editors want to edit HTML.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The trick here is selecting the table, once the entire table is selected, you can edit the table and all its properties via the `Table` (editor) button.

The best way to select the entire table is just click in any of its cells, and then go to the `Current Elements` dropdown in the Ribbon. It will currently be standing on `Table Cell <td>`, now you can select `* Table <table>` from the dropdown, and then you have the entire table selected. Just press the `Table` button in the ribbon next, and you are on your way.

[image: Component view]

Comment: A really good tip - far nicer than my 'use Internet Explorer' suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

Can you ask the editors to try another browser?

From my experience, Internet Explorer allows editors to select a table that has already been created and edit using the normal Table Builder.

Last time I tried it, neither Firefox nor Chrome allowed you to 'grab' the table and do this - meaning that an editor's only option was to head into the `Source` tab.